# If column A has a value, summarise variables in column B, until next variable in column A appears

Tags: r, loops

I have performed an experiment in which people are moving around cubes until they made a figure they like. When they like a figure, they save if and creates a new one. The script tracked time and number of moves between all figures safes.

I now have a column (A) with number of moves between each save and a column (B) with the time between each move until the figure is saved. Thus column A is filled with NA's and then a number (signifies figure safe) and column B has time in seconds in all rows (except from first row) signifing all the moves made.

Excerpt of data:

```
A   B           C

NA  1.6667798   
NA  3.3326443   
NA  3.5506110   
NA  11.4995562  
NA  1.4334849   
NA  4.9502637   
NA  2.1161980   
NA  4.7833326   
NA  2.8500842   
NA  4.0331373   
NA  4.3498785   
12  5.0910905   Sum

NA  4.2424078   
NA  1.7332665   
NA  1.5341006   
3   4.8923275   Sum

NA  4.1064621   
NA  3.3498289   
NA  1.6002373   
3   6.0122170   Sum
```

I have tried several loop options, but I cannot seem make it work properly. 
I made this loop, but it is not doing the correct calculation in column C.

```
data$C <- rep(NA, nrow(data))

for (i in unique(data$id)) {
  C <- which(data$id == i & data$type == "moveblock")
  for (e in 1:length(C)){
    if (e == 1){
    data$C[C[e]] = C[e] - which(data$id == i)[1]  
    }
    else if (e > 1){
    data$C[C[e]] = C[e] + C[e+1]+1}
  } 

  d_times <- which(data$id == i)
  for (t in 2:length(d_times)){
    data$B[d_times[t]] <- data$time[d_times[t]] - data$time[d_times[t-1]]
  }
}
```

I want a new column (C) which has the sum of all rows from column B until a figure has been saved = a number in column A. In other words, I want to calculate the total time it took the subject to make all the moves before saving the figure.

Hope anyone can figure this out!

Comment: Please provide `data` in a more friendly format, e.g. using `dput` or `dplyr::tribble`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create groups based on occurrence of non `NA` values and take `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 group_by(group = lag(cumsum(!is.na(A)), default = 0)) %>% 
 summarise(sum = sum(B, na.rm = TRUE))

#  group   sum
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0  49.7
#2     1  12.4
#3     2  15.1
```

In base R, we can use `aggregate` to do the same

```
aggregate(B~c(0, head(cumsum(!is.na(A)), -1)), df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 12L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L), B = c(1.6667798, 3.3326443, 
3.550611, 11.4995562, 1.4334849, 4.9502637, 2.116198, 4.7833326, 
2.8500842, 4.0331373, 4.3498785, 5.0910905, 4.2424078, 1.7332665, 
1.5341006, 4.8923275, 4.1064621, 3.3498289, 1.6002373, 6.012217
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: The aggregate line makes the sum of column B, however, it misses the last variable 5.0910905 (in the same row as 12)

Comment: @KathrineBredahl You are right, can you check the updated version of the answer?

Comment: It makes the first sum correct, namely 49.657061 sec. However, when I extract the edits (column A values) from the large dataset, I get 6371 rows, but your calculation of sum times makes 6372 rows. This might be due to the last row in the large dataset, as the last move made was NOT a save and therefore is assigned a value via the aggregate function, but does not need one. Or am I all wrong?

Comment: Hi, I notice a problem with the column C results. The dataset includes multiple subjects doing the task in a time frame of 20 minutes. When the row changes from one person to the next, column C calculates the B variables into the next persons' move time. So if column B has values in it after the last safe (column A) which many people have, then it should not add these values to the next person.
So right now, the sum (in column C) is calculated from edit to edit (column B values) and does not account for when the subject changes.

Comment: @KathrineBredahl Do you have different `subject` or different `person` ? In any case, you also need to add them in the grouping list. Try `aggregate(B~c(0, head(cumsum(!is.na(A)), -1)) + person + subject, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I used both the term person and subject for same. The column in which I differentiate is called "id", but when I add this to the grouping as you added subject, it does solve the problem.  
This is the code I used: 
aggregate(B~c(0, head(cumsum(!is.na(A)), -1)) + id, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: No adding "id" did not solve the problem. It still takes values above the last edit (column B) even though id has changed

Comment: @KathrineBredahl In that case, I would suggest you to ask a new question including these new details in it. Adding changes into this question would invalidate current answers and confuse future readers as well .

Comment: I have now created a new question. If interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799607/sum-of-column-b-move-time-depending-on-column-a-edits-and-id

Answer (score 0):

You could create a matrix out of the periods (i.e. `seq`uences) and sum the values of column `B` accordingly. For this create vector `saved` that indicates where a subject has "saved" and list sequences using `apply()`. Finally the `sapply()` loops over the sequences in the `periods` list.

```
saved <- which(!is.na(dat$A))
periods <- apply(cbind(c(1, (saved + 1)[-3]), saved), 1, function(x) seq(x[1], x[2]))
dat$C[saved] <- sapply(periods, function(x) sum(dat$B[x]))
```

#### Result

```
dat$C
# [1]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# [10]       NA       NA 49.65706       NA       NA       NA 12.40210       NA       NA
# [19]       NA 15.06875
```

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 12L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L), B = c(1.6667798, 3.3326443, 
3.550611, 11.4995562, 1.4334849, 4.9502637, 2.116198, 4.7833326, 
2.8500842, 4.0331373, 4.3498785, 5.0910905, 4.2424078, 1.7332665, 
1.5341006, 4.8923275, 4.1064621, 3.3498289, 1.6002373, 6.012217
), C = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```